# Customize DataGrid for Win CE Device

Tags: c#, datagrid, windows-ce

I'm writing an application for windows ce, so I have to use VS 2008.

I'm showing some Data in a dataGrid-Control (DataGridView NOT available!), and I want to customize it.

things like grid.Columns[i].width etc are not working on these controls.

I need to change the columns width and header texts, how can I achieve that?
The datagrid gets it entries at runtime with this line:

```
dgLatestPositions.DataSource = items;
```

items is a list<> containing objects, the table got 2 columns.
The view of the dataGrid is working fine, except these issues.

edit: Maybe something like that? (It's not working yet either)

```
DataGridTableStyle t = new DataGridTableStyle();
t.GridColumnStyles[0].HeaderText = "Coding";
t.GridColumnStyles[1].HeaderText = "Amount";
dgLatestPositions.TableStyles.Add(t);
```

***Edit:***

All Items are contained in a List.
The article-objects looks this way:
public class lastChanges

```
{
    public long coding { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
}
```

The Table shows up like this (example)

coding    |amount

0123456789|3

0829346128|4

What I need to do is resize the first column and change the captions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We too have an app that requires back support under WindowsCE and has to be done in VS2008.  You are very close, and what we did was created a base-class data grid for display and added a method to add the columns we wanted getting the heading text, binding column source and then the width.  Here is our method and the "myTblStyle" is your DataGridTableStyle "t" variable.

```
public void AddColumn(string hdr, string colName, int colWidth)
{
    DataGridTextBoxColumn tbc = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
    tbc.HeaderText = hdr;
    tbc.MappingName = colName;
    tbc.Width = colWidth;
    myTblStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(tbc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have 'article' objects, each contains 2 values, these values are presented in the grid. All the objects are in a List<article>. How can I use these as colName? I'm a bit confused now

Comment: @Marcel, since I use DataTable as the source for our stuff, not lists, I am just letting it know which column in the table.  If yours is a List, a list of what.  Is there a field/property per the list<type>.  If nothing else, ignore the "colName" binding and just get the width from it.  You don't describe what your "list<>" object structure is... but grab the field from that object structure.

Comment: @Marcel, then I would think that the mapping you need just needs to reference the corresponding "coding" and "amount" properties of the list object.  Could be case-sensitive on the binding.  Just note you could have a column heading of "$ Amount" and the column binding of "Amount" or "amount" based on the actual binding... hence difference in the column header text vs what is actually bound for display of data.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you very much!, Note: The header is working, but I still need the size :/